# why is my delete button in React JS not working?

Tags: reactjs, onclick

sth is wrong with my onClick or sth but when i click on the red delete button, the console doesn't show 'delete', there is no mistake announced tho...anybody knows what is wrong plz help me! fanks!

This is my Tasks.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import Task from './Task'

const Tasks = ({tasks, onDelete}) => {
    
    return (
        <div>
         {tasks.map((task)=>(<Task key={task.id} task={task} onDelete={onDelete} /> ))} 
        </div>
    )
}

export default Tasks
```

This is my Task.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import {FaTimes} from 'react-icons/fa'
const Task = ({task, onDelete}) => {
    return (
        <div className='task'>
           <h3>{task.text} <FaTimes style={{color:'red', cursor:'pointer'}} onClick={onDelete} /></h3>
           <p>{task.day}</p> 
        </div>
    )
}

export default Task
```

This is my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import "./index.css"
import {useState} from 'react'
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Tasks from "./components/Tasks";


  const App = () => {
    const [tasks, setTasks]=useState([
      {
          id:1,
          text:'Doctors Appointment',
          day:'Feb 5th at 2:30pm',
          reminder: true,
      },
      {
          id:2,
          text:'Meeting at School',
          day:'Feb 6th at 1:30pm',
          reminder: true,
      },
      {
          id:3,
          text:'Food Shopping',
          day:'Feb 5th at 2:30pm',
          reminder: false,
      },
    ])
    //delete Task 
    const deleteTask = (id) =>{
      console.log('delete', id)
    }

  return (
<div className="container">
 <Header  />
 <Tasks tasks={tasks} ONDelete={deleteTask}   />
</div>
 )
}

export default App
```

My App.js, Task.js and Tasks.js are in my components folder which is in my src folder

Comment: In your `App.js`, by `ONDelete` do you mean `onDelete`?

Comment: yah i fixed that but it's still not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

`deleteTask` consumes a task id, but none is passed to it.

```
//delete Task 
const deleteTask = (id) => {
  console.log('delete', id)
}
```

There's also a typo, the `Tasks` component takes an `onDelete` prop, not an `ONDelete`, so `onDelete` is actually undefined in subsequent children.

## Solution

Pass `onDelete` to `Tasks` correctly.

```
<Tasks tasks={tasks} onDelete={deleteTask} />
```

When clicked, pass a task id.

```
const Task = ({task, onDelete}) => {
  return (
    <div className='task'>
     <h3>
       {task.text}
       <FaTimes
         style={{ color:'red', cursor:'pointer' }}
         onClick={() => onDelete(task.id)} // <-- pass task id
       />
     </h3>
     <p>{task.day}</p> 
    </div>
  )
}
```

[image: Edit why-is-my-delete-button-in-react-js-not-working]

Comment: I fixed the typo and pass the task id to onclick but it's still not working...

Comment: @DuongDuong I copy/pasted your code into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/why-is-my-delete-button-in-react-js-not-working-p85ei?file=/src/App.js) and applied my suggested changes and see the task id logged out in the `deleteTask` callback. I added a link to the sandbox in my answer. Please check it.

Comment: i changed it the same way as you suggested in your codesandbox and the 'delete' can't still log out man, and it announces the mistake on the onDelete function in the task.js that you have fixed (it says 'onDelete is not a function')...

Comment: @DuongDuong Can you create a running codesandbox of your own that reproduces the issue that we can inspect and live debug? I suspect you've just missed a small, subtle detail somewhere.

Comment: i copied and pasted my code in codesandbox. This is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-bush-mygjr?file=/src/App.js.

Comment: thank you for helping me. I appreciate your effort!

Comment: @DuongDuong You had another, different typo in `App` this time. You have `<Tasks tasks={tasks} OnDelete={deleteTask} />` instead of `<Tasks tasks={tasks} onDelete={deleteTask} />`, i.e. `OnDelete` versus `onDelete`. Javascript is a case-sensitive language, variables `onDelete` and `OnDelete` are two different entities.